# Variance Inflation Factors test on grouped regression results

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataset of mulitiple financial variables, such as ROA, ROE, for multiple stocks in a data frame. I run a regression for each stock on these variables but I run the regression by group to prevent multiple calls to `lm()` I use the code below:

```r
df_fit <- dataset.for.reg %>% group_by(ticker) %>%
  do(fiitedmod = lm(ROA ~ SIZE + LEV + TANG + DPO, data = .))

df_coef <- tidy(df_fit, fiitedmod)
```

How to I use the `vif()` function from the `car` package in a situation like this where I do not have an object of the class `lm`? Do I have no choice but to use a loop on the `lm` or multiple calls to `lm()`?

Sample data below

```r
mydata <- "num,ticker,ROA,SIZE,LEV,TANG,DPO
1,ARL,1,2,9,2,6
2,ARL,2,3,12,3,6
3,ARL,3,9,7,1,7
4,ARL,4,7,6,4,8
5,ARL,12,5,8,5,10
6,ARL,9,4,11,6,4
7,ARL,11,12,10,7,5
8,ARL,6,6,5,8,9
9,ARL,10,8,4,9,11
10,ARL,5,1,3,10,3
11,ARL,8,11,2,12,2
12,ARL,7,10,1,11,1
13,NHM,22,24,19,23,13
14,NHM,24,19,13,24,16
15,NHM,23,18,14,13,14
16,NHM,20,13,15,14,12
17,NHM,19,15,16,15,15
18,NHM,21,17,17,16,15
19,NHM,17,16,18,17,15
20,NHM,16,14,20,19,15
21,NHM,13,20,21,18,15
22,NHM,15,22,22,20,15
23,NHM,14,21,23,21,15
24,NHM,18,23,24,22,15
25,MUR,36,29,36,33,17
26,MUR,35,28,33,35,18
27,MUR,33,27,30,32,22
28,MUR,26,35,35,30,20
29,MUR,25,25,34,34,20
30,MUR,31,26,31,36,20
31,MUR,34,36,32,31,21
32,MUR,32,30,29,29,21
33,MUR,30,31,28,28,19
34,MUR,27,32,27,26,19
35,MUR,28,34,25,27,21
36,MUR,29,33,26,25,21
37,NED,47,43,48,39,31
38,NED,39,44,47,40,29
39,NED,37,45,46,41,28
40,NED,38,46,45,42,30
41,NED,41,48,44,43,32
42,NED,42,37,43,44,33
43,NED,44,41,42,45,11
44,NED,45,47,41,46,23
45,NED,43,39,40,47,24
46,NED,40,40,39,48,25
47,NED,48,42,37,37,26
48,NED,46,38,38,38,27
49,SHP,53,54,59,50,35
50,SHP,55,55,58,51,36
51,SHP,54,57,57,52,37
52,SHP,51,51,56,53,38
53,SHP,60,59,51,54,39
54,SHP,59,60,54,55,40
55,SHP,58,58,53,57,41
56,SHP,50,49,52,56,43
57,SHP,49,52,49,58,45
58,SHP,57,50,50,59,44
59,SHP,56,56,55,60,42
60,NPK,65,71,61,65,46
61,NPK,62,61,69,63,52
62,NPK,69,64,63,61,51
63,NPK,67,65,60,62,53
64,NPK,72,67,64,64,47
65,NPK,71,68,66,67,48
66,NPK,68,69,70,66,49
67,NPK,66,66,71,70,50
68,NPK,70,63,68,68,53
69,NPK,61,62,67,71,53
70,NPK,63,72,65,72,53
71,NPK,64,70,62,69,53
72,ACL,82,81,73,80,57
73,ACL,81,82,72,74,55
74,ACL,84,79,76,82,54
75,ACL,80,78,74,77,56
76,ACL,74,75,75,76,56
77,ACL,77,76,77,83,56
78,ACL,79,73,78,78,56
79,ACL,73,84,79,84,56
80,ACL,78,74,80,79,56
81,ACL,76,83,81,81,56
82,ACL,75,80,83,75,56
83,ACL,83,77,82,73,56
84,CLS,85,95,87,87,67
85,CLS,86,96,89,89,68
86,CLS,87,85,88,88,52
87,CLS,96,86,94,90,58
88,CLS,95,88,91,91,59
89,CLS,93,87,93,92,60
90,CLS,94,89,95,93,61
91,CLS,91,90,92,94,62
92,CLS,89,91,90,95,63
93,CLS,92,92,86,96,64
94,CLS,90,93,85,85,65
95,CLS,88,94,84,86,66"

dataset.for.reg <- read.table(text = mydata, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you not just run them for each lm in the original list? `lapply(df_fit[[2]],vif)`

Comment: Does what I threw up there work for your needs? Or are you trying to do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I'd formalize the answer

`lapply(df_fit[[2]],vif)`